# why is push not updating the list

Tags: html, angularjs

**javascript**

```
$scope.addCustomer = function() {    
    $scope.customers=[{name:'bob',city:'delhi'},{name:'david',city:'bombay'}];
    $scope.customers.push({name:$scope.newCustomer.name,city:$scope.newCustomer.city
}
```

**html**

```
<br/>
Customer name :<br />
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
<br/>
Customer city :<br />
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
<button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add customer</button>
```

I tried listing all the customer names in an unordered list but the new customer is not getting added to the list.

How can i add the niew customer to the list ?

Comment: Your JS has invalid syntax.

Comment: can you please pin-point it ?

Comment: `$scope.customers.push({...});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.customers=[{name:'bob',city:'delhi'},{name:'david',city:'bombay'}];
$scope.addCustomer = function() {
    $scope.customers.push({name:$scope.newCustomer.name,city:$scope.newCustomer.city});
}
```

Working exmaple: http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/aVWpQ/

Comment: it works fine for the link u have provided. but nothing is getting reflected in my browser when i run in my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign value to `$scope.customers` in `addCustomer()`.

You can try this:

```
<div ng-controller="test">
    Customer name :<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
    <br/>
    Customer city :<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add customer</button>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>city</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
                <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
                <td>{{customer.city}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    function test($scope){
        $scope.customers=[{name:'bob',city:'delhi'},{name:'david',city:'bombay'}];
        $scope.addCustomer = function(){
            $scope.customers.push({name:$scope.newCustomer.name,city:$scope.newCustomer.city});
            alert($scope.customers.length)
        }
    }       
</script>
```